# JPA - Convert double format from aaa,bbb to aaa.bbb

Tags: java, floating-point

In the web application I am currently building, my client insists that he is able to input decimal numbers using comma "," as the separation point. Is there any annotation equivalent to the following:

```
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

so that the cast can made automatically or do I have to manually convert the input ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that with JPA? If it is a numeric data element it should already be a number. The conversion from an input string happens long before.

Comment: I use Spring Webflow and all my jsp fields are directly bound to the model. Thus it would be very convenient to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this in your UI layer. There is no such thing in JPA.